# Dialogic API for D/4PCI

Tags: java, c++, asp.net-ajax

Where can I find the .net API for the Dialogic D/4PCI.  This is an older card.  Also, what are other alternatives for an API.  I would prefer to work in either C# (.net) or Java.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](http://www.dialogic.com/products/docs/appnotes/11170-dalogic-apis-net-apps-an.pdf) on the dialogic website. Mentions C++ and Visual Basic. Don't know anything about this.

Good luck.